# Systems and Gravational PE

Tags: newtonian-gravity, potential-energy

Can an object that is part of a system of objects have gravitational potential energy if the Earth is not part of the said system? For example say i have an incline and a block near the surface of the earth. If the block is at the top of the incline and i define my system to be the block and the incline, then does the block have any gravitational PE?

Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gravitational potential energy is not "inside an object". It is shared between two objects that attract each other. It is stored in the *system* or *field* between them.

If you define your system as one of these objects alone, then it get's a bit difficult. Your system will not be *isolated*. Then you cannot rely on e.g. the energy conservation law, because you essentially are allowing energy to exit and enter the system; as you say, removing Earth will severally change the system you have defined, since the external force changes. And without this force there is no tendency of the object to move, thus no stored energy.

So, defining your system as only a part of a gravitational potential energy system is best to avoid.

Comment: Second paragraph second sentence seems to have gotten mangled, I assume you mean "Your system will not be isolated".