# Can gravity ever be considered a non-conservative force?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, potential-energy, conservative-field

I came across this definition of a conservative force:

> "conservative force is a force which doesn't change the total mechanical energy".

So does that mean that if gravity is an external force to your system it can be considered to be a non-conservative force?

Comment: Yikes.  I understand what the author of that definition is trying to say, but it's a lousy definition of a conservative force.   It raises questions like yours, questions which simply don't arise in a good definition.  No, gravity cannot be considered to be a non-conservative force.  Possibly related:  some texts write $W_{NC} = KE+PE$.  For related reasons, this is a lousy statement of conservation of energy.

Comment: Related question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/323297/2451

Answer (score 1):

That's a terrible definition of conservative force. By the logic of that definition, there are either *no* conservative forces, or the definition of "conservative" depends on your choice of system (which means that a force alone can never be "conservative;" it's only conservative with respect to certain systems. The fact that we refer to gravity as a "conservative force" without reference to a system should convince you that this is an improper definition). Here's a proof of that statement:

Let $F$ be a conservative force. We can interpret the definition two ways: either

a) $F$ conserves the mechanical energy of a *particular* system, or equivalently *some set of* particular systems; or

b) $F$ conserves the mechanical energy of *every* system.

If we assume a), then the definition of "conservative force" doesn't depend on only the force; it requires a force *and a choice of system(s)*. A force, under a), can only be conservative with respect to a particular system. Since I can always choose a system in which $F$ is external, then there is no way to say that $F$ is "conservative" without respect to a given system. This is an improper definition for the reasons in parentheses above.

If we assume b), then if $F$ is conservative, it conserves mechanical energy in every system. Let's choose one such system. We can always construct a new system in which $F$ is external, meaning that it does not conserve mechanical energy. Therefore, $F$ does not conserve energy in every system, so $F$ is not conservative. This is a contradiction, so there are no conservative forces under this definition.

The proper definition of "conservative force" is the following:

***A force is conservative if and only if it can be written as the gradient of a scalar function $U$, which is often called the "potential."***

This ensures that we can have a system-independent, logically consistent definition of conservative, and as such, this is (one of) the (many equivalent) definition(s) we actually use.

Comment: Although we usually adopt the sign convention $F=-\nabla U$.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned already the definition of a conservative force given in the question is not precise. A conservative force is a force whose work done on a system in a loop is zero. Mathematically one can express the same definition as 
$$\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{F}=0$$
If a force follows this relation then it is conservative. In case of gravity the force in spherical coordinates is 
$$F_r=\frac{GMm}{r²}$$
$$F_{\theta}=F_{\phi}=0$$
Using the relation for curl in spherical coordinates given [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates) one can obtain the relation
$$\vec{\nabla}\times \vec{F}_{gravity}=0$$
Hence gravity is a conservative force in every frame.

Answer (score 0):

An external force is one which alters the mechanical energy of a system , hence if mechanical energy is given by PE + KE ..therefore gravity has already been accounted for ...and due to this can't be considered an external force since it will never change the total mechanical energy of a system ,hence gravity is not considered an external force

Comment: It depends on your choice of system.  If you drop a book, and you take your system to be the book, then gravity is an external force.  (And it is conservative.)

Comment: @garyp If I take the system to be book and Earth then it will be an internal force ,right?

Comment: @Abhinav  That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the total mechanical energy $E$, being the sum of a potential energy $V(\mathbf{x})$ and kinetic energy $\frac{1}{2}m\left ( \frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}}{\mathrm{d}t}^2 \right )$:

$$ E = \frac{1}{2}m\left ( \frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}}{\mathrm{d}t}^2 \right ) + V(\mathbf{x}),$$ which is termed *mechanical energy*.

For this to be **conserved**, i.e. a **constant** in time, then its total time derivative must vanish:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}E}{\mathrm{d}t} = 0, $$

where by the chain rule:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}E}{\mathrm{d}t} =  \sum_{k=x,y,z} \left [ m\frac{\mathrm{d}x_k}{\mathrm{d}t}\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x_k}{\mathrm{d}t^2} + \frac{\partial V}{\partial x_k}\frac{\mathrm{d}x_k}{\mathrm{d}t} \right ] =  \sum_{k=x,y,z} \left ( m\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x_k}{\mathrm{d}t^2} + \frac{\partial V}{\partial x_k}\right )\frac{\mathrm{d}x_k}{\mathrm{d}t} = 0.$$

You recognise the first term $ m\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x_k}{\mathrm{d}t^2}  $ as the expression for the force $F_k$ in Newton's second law.

The equality is satisfied only if $m\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x_k}{\mathrm{d}t^2}   = F_k = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial x_k}$, meaning $\mathbf{F} = -\nabla V$. 
 In such a case, the force would be called a *conservative force*.

There are a lot of equivalent definitions for a conservative force, all which stem from the essential one: a conservative force is any force that can be written as the gradient of a potential $\mathbf{F} = -\nabla V$.

- By the rules of vector calculus, $\nabla \times \mathbf{F} \propto \nabla \times \nabla V = 0$, so any conservative force field has no vorticity, $\nabla \times \mathbf{F} = 0$.
- By Stokes's theorem, the above constraint can be made into a path integral one: $\iint \nabla \times \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{S} = \oint \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{x} = 0$ for *any* path, since the left hand side is *always* zero, regardless of the surface $\mathbf{S}$. So any conservative force is path independent.

Comment: Your argument proves the following: "If we assume that total mechanical energy is conserved, then any forces present must be conservative." It doesn't hold for the other half of the if-and-only-if equivalence of the definition: "If a force is conservative, then it doesn't change the total mechanical energy of a system." It's clear that in an open system, even conservative external forces change the total mechanical energy, so that half of the definition fails. As such, I don't see how this addresses the question, which was about the definition as a whole, not just half of it.

Comment: Not only that, but it only addresses the case of the motion of a single particle, which is not an assumption that was included in the definition.